# IDataObject asynchronous operation completed notification

Tags: windows, winapi, drag-and-drop, windows-shell, windows-10-desktop

There are:

1. Windows Explorer window opened in a folder (next `Folder A`) with a large file (next `File`).
2. My application window (next `App`) is registered as a drop target and implements [`IDropTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleidl/nn-oleidl-idroptarget).
3. A user associates the `App` with another folder on his system (next `Folder B`).
4. The user wants to copy/move the `File` from the `Folder A` to the `Folder B` via the `App`.
5. The user starts the `File` drag operation from the `Folder A` to the `App`.
6. When the `App` receives `DragEnter`, it gets `IDropTarger` of the `Folder B` and call the `Folder B` `DragEnter`. When the `App` receives `DragOver`, `DragLeave`, `DragDrop` it calls the `Folder B` `DragOver`, `DragLeave`, `DragDrop` respectively.
7. When the `App` calls `DragDrop` of `Folder B`, Windows Explorer starts asynchronous copy/move operation of the `File` (next `Operation`). UI of the `App` is not blocked and the user can close the `App`.

The `App` doesn't manage an `IDataObject` of the `File` and doesn't control the `Operation`. If the user closes the `App` during the `Operation`, the `Operation` will be aborted.

I don't want:

1. To disable the `Operation` async via [`IDataObjectAsyncCapability::SetAsyncMode(False)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/nf-shldisp-idataobjectasynccapability-setasyncmode).
2. To do the `Operation` (copy or move file) myself via [Shell Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard) because I don't want to handle all possible exceptions if the `Operation` fails. Let Windows Explorer do it.

I'm looking for a way to get a notification about the end of the `Operation`. If user closes the `App` while the `Operation` is in progress, the `App` warns the user about it.

I tried the following. Collect [`FORMATETC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/ns-objidl-formatetc) with [`IDataObject::EnumFormatEtc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-idataobject-enumformatetc) and call [`IDataObject::DAdvice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-idataobject-dadvise) for each:

```
FORMATETC formatetcs[64];
ULONG fetched;

IEnumFORMATETC *pEnumFormatEtc;
if (dataObject.EnumFormatEtc(DATADIR_GET, &pEnumFormatEtc) == S_OK) {
  enumFormatEtc.Next(64, formatetcs, &fetched);
}
// 'fetched' is around 18
for (int I = 0; I < fetched; I++) {
  HRESULT hr;
  DWORD connection;
  hr = dataObject.DAdvice(&formatetcs[I], ADVF_NODATA | ADVF_DATAONSTOP, pAdvSink, &connection);
}
```

I got [`hr == OLE_E_ADVISENOTSUPPORTED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-idataobject-dadvise#return-value) for each `FORMATETC`. Also I tried [`FORMATETC{0, NULL, -1, -1, -1}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-idataobject-dadvise#notes-to-callers) with the same result.

How to receive notification of the end of the operation? Or how to submit the operation to Windows Explorer process?

Comment: Are you talking about this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/datascenarios?redirectedfrom=MSDN#dragging-and-dropping-shell-objects-asynchronously ? But you don't seem to be using IAsyncOperation/IDataObjectAsyncCapability ?

Comment: No. My application is not an `IDataSource` and not real `IDropTarget`. It just passes `IDropTarget` calls to Shell object, for instance a folder. I don't create or control an `IDataObject`. The `IDataObject` is controlled by Windows Explorer.

Comment: What do you mean by "Drag and drop file copy/move operations in Windows Explorer are asynchronous." then? The Windows Shell adds enough information to an IDataObject to be able to do file operation. Or provide a reproductible sample project.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I updated the issue description.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The dataobject should contain all needed format to do file operation like all CFSTR_FILExxx etc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard

Comment: I don't want to do the `Operation` (copy or move file) myself, let the Windows Explorer do it.